# Select the elements, of the first node of XML (linq,C#)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My question is often asked at several places, but I have an xml, without attributes, so I can't use those methods.
My XML's structure is this:

```
<offers>
 <offer>
    <seller>
      <citizen>
        <name>A name</name>
        <id>An ID</id>
      </citizen>
    </seller>
    <amount>Number</amount>
    <exchange-rate>Rate</exchange-rate>
  </offer>
.
.
.
  <offer>....
  </offer>
</offers>
```

I managed to populate a multicolumn listview with this code:

```
var offers = from o in loaded.Elements("offers").Elements("offer") select o;
     foreach (var vmi in offers)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item = lista1.Items.Add(vmi.Descendants("name").First().Value);
                item.SubItems.Add(vmi.Element("amount").Value);
                item.SubItems.Add(vmi.Element("exchange-rate").Value);
            }
```

**But now, I need to select data-s (name,amount,exchange-rate) between the first `<offer></offer>`**

Could you please provide the code for this in C#? I tried the FirstNode, or the First() but I am stucked. Thank you in advance!

***UPDATE!***
I forgot to mention that the citizen tag may varying in the xml. It is citizen or company. That's why I used the Descendants method. But if you can show me a better way, to handle this. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstOffer = loaded.Element("offers").Element("offer");
var name = firstOffer.Element("seller").Element("citizen").Element("name").Value;
var id = firstOffer.Element("seller").Element("citizen").Element("id").Value;
var amount = firstOffer.Element("amount").Value;
var exchangeRate = firstOffer.Element("exchange-rate").Value;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the citizen tag may varying in the xml. It is citizen or company. That's why I used the Descendants method. But if you can show me a better way, to handle this. I would appreciate it.
Btw. the code, you recently send, with my little change 
(var name = firstOffer.Descendants("name").First().Value;) gives error in runtime.
NullreferenceException in the first row. So I deleted the: .Element("offers") part, then the error points to the row with the Descendants method.
I hope I am understandeble:S

Comment: I made a mistake loading the xml file, that's why it didn't work. The right code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(xmlAddress);
var first = xml.Element("offer");
var name = first.Descendants("name").First().Value;
var amount = first.Element("amount").Value;
var exchangeRate = first.Element("exchange-rate").Value;
```